# ng-enter-stagger animation not working on safari

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a ng-enter-stagger animation that works on chrome and firefox but not on safari.

I have prefixed the transition definition with -webkit- but it is not working on safari. See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/NicholasMurray/pen/OVZeQK) for a demo of the issue

```
    .animate-repeat.ng-enter-stagger,
    .animate-repeat.ng-leave-stagger {
        -webkit-transition-delay: 400ms;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
        transition-delay: 400ms;
        transition-duration: 0s;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick check in Safari, I turned on autoprefixer under **CSS settings** -> **Vendor Prefixing** in CodePen.  That seems to fix  the latest Safari as the effect looked good to me. If you've got any sort of build step, I highly recommend adding Autoprefixer into the mix. If you do, problem solved!

If you're a DIYer, when you're vendor prefixing properties and using transitions/transforms, you have to vendor prefix the property values as well:

```
    .animate-repeat.ng-enter,
    .animate-repeat.ng-leave {
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1750ms;
        transition: transform 1750ms; 
    }
```

In several instances in the CodePen you linked to above, you're not doing this.  Doing so should fix the issue! The reason you had some effects working in some browsers was because they supported the un-prefixed versions that you had written correctly.

Another *hacky* way to get around problems like this is to use `-webkit-transition: all` instead of specifying all the different properties, though this will impact any and all properties that change.

Comment: perfect just the comprehensive answer I was looking for.